# How to create class for JSON web service result in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

how can I create class for JSON web service result? This is my JSON result which i get from google api. so, how to create class and deserialization for this JSON object.
[image]

I created class to deserialization this JSON object like this,

```
string mapdetail = e.Result;
        var djosn = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(mapResult));
        var mstr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mapdetail));
        mapResult reslt = (mapResult)djosn.ReadObject(mstr);
```

mapResult class:

```
[DataContract]
public class mapResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string status
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public IList<Resultdetail> result
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

So i creadet list for result details and others:

```
[DataContract]
public class Resultdetail
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> types
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string formatted_address
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public List<object> address_components
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Geometry> geometry
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

[DataContract]
public class Geometry
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<GeoLocation> location
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string location_type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public List<object> viewport
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public List<object> bounds
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

[DataContract]
public class GeoLocation
{
    [DataMember]
    public double lat
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public double lng
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

Now I'm getting Null reference;

[image]

Comment: In future, please try and include the text of code (or json objects) rather than pictures. It makes it much easier to try and recreate what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a few issues with your DatContract classes.

I've corrected these below, commented out the original lines and added a comment about what was specifically wrong.

```
[DataContract]
public class mapResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    //public IList<Resultdetail> result { get; set; }
    // Misspelt property name and use of interface rather than concrete type
    public List<Resultdetail> results { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Resultdetail
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<object> address_components { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    //public List<Geometry> geometry { get; set; }
    // Json does not contain an array/list of these
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Geometry
{
    [DataMember]
    //public List<GeoLocation> location { get; set; }
    // Json does not contain an array/list of these
    public GeoLocation location { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    // public List<object> viewport { get; set; }  
    // Json does not contain an array/list of these
    public object viewport { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    //public List<object> bounds { get; set; }
    // Json does not contain an array/list of these
    public object bounds { get; set; }
}
```

The following code shows that this works:

```
var jsonStr = "{\"status\": \"OK\", \"results\": [ { \"types\": [ \"route\" ], \"formatted_address\": \"7th Main Rd, Koramangala, sengaluru, Karnataka 560034, India\", \"address_components\": [ { \"long_name\": \"7th Main Rd\", \"short_name\": \"7th Main Rd\", \"types\": [ \"route\" ] }, { \"long_name\": \"Koramangala\", \"short_name\": \"Koramangala\", \"types\": [ \"sublocality\", \"political\" ] }, { \"long_name\": \"Bengaluru\", \"short_name\": \"Bengaluru\", \"types\": [ \"locality\", \"political\" ] }, { \"long_name\": \"sengaluru\", \"short_name\": \"sengaluru\", \"types\": [ \"administrative_area_level_2\", \"political\" ] }, { \"long_name\": \"Karnataka\", \"short_name\": \"Karnataka\", \"types\": [ \"administrative_area_level_1\", \"political\" ] }, { \"long_name\": \"India\", \"short_name\": \"IN\", \"types\": [ \"country\", \"political\" ] }, { \"long_name\": \"560034\", \"short_name\": \"560034\", \"types\": [ \"postal_code\" ] }],\"geometry\": { \"location\":{ \"lat\": 12.9259085, \"lng\": 77.6334715 }, \"location_type\": \"GEOMETRIC_CENTER\", \"viewport\": { \"southwest\": { \"lat\": 12.9227118, \"lng\": 77.6301852 }, \"northeast\": { \"lat\": 12.929007, \"lng\": 77.6364805}}, \"bounds\": { \"southwest\": { \"lat\": 12.9247615, \"lng\": 77.6330486 },\"northeast\": { \"lat\": 12.9269574, \"lng\": 77.6336171 }}}}]}";

// If using json.net (http://json.codeplex.com/)
var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mapResult>(jsonStr);

// If using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
var djosn = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(mapResult));
var mstr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonStr));
des = (mapResult)djosn.ReadObject(mstr);

var latitude = des.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
var longitude = des.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
```

Note that my code is tested with your sample json object only and is not guaranteed to work with everything returned by the web service. You're also deserialising quite a lot to `object` which may be awkward to work with if you want more than just the latitude and longitude.

Comment: I can't get JsonConvert in WP7. how to get that one? Is there any namespace  have to add?

Comment: @selladurai Sorry I was using Json.net (Silvelight version) and forgot to say

Comment: @selladurai I've updated answer with a version of code which uses `DataContractJsonSerializer`. I'd recommend using json.net though as it's faster!

Comment: windows phone 7 assembly does not accept json.net DLL file. then how to do?

Comment: @selladurai When you download json.net there are several versions on the bin directory. You need to use the Silverlight version.

Answer (score 2):

I note that your top-level list is called `result` whereas the JSON name is `results` btw - could it be as simple as that? Maybe the deserializer is ignoring the `results` value because you don't have a property of that name.

If that doesn't work... You've got 7 dereferencing operations in that statement. (4 obvious ones and 3 array indexing operations). That's an awful lot of possible failure points. I suggest you put a break point on that statement (to break before it executes) and then use the watch window to look at what results you've actually got.

(Personally I've used [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) in Windows Phone 7 rather than the built-in libraries, but I'm sure the latter should work too.)